# Secure websocket exchange

Tags: websocket, dart

I sought on internet about this thread. If I understood, an utilisation of https or wss, require a SSl certificat ? These method can secure the data exchange ?

I read a document about RSA. It's look good, and secure. But, how I can implement these ? I found a pub package named "cipher". Is it good ?

Actually my code look like this for server-side :

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

ft_handle_error(error) => print("The are on error $error");

handle_msg(String msg) => print("Message received : $msg");

void    ft_server_html(HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request.uri.path == '/')
    {
        request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED;
        request.response.headers.contentType = new ContentType('text', 'plain');
        request.response.write('Hello toi !');
    }
    else
        request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    request.response.close();
}

void    ft_ws_server(HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request.uri.path == '/ws')
    {
        WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request)
        .then((socket)
        {
            socket.listen(handle_msg);
            socket.add("Recu");
        })
        .whenComplete(request.response.close);
    }
    else
        request.response.close();
}

void    main()
{
    HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8080)
    .then((server) => server.listen(ft_server_html))
    .catchError(ft_handle_error);
    HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 4040)
    .then((ws_server) => ws_server.listen(ft_ws_server))
    .catchError(ft_handle_error);
}
```

And client-side

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void    main()
{
    WebSocket wss;

    wss = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:4040/ws');
    wss.onOpen.listen((_) => wss.send("From browser"));
    wss.onMessage.listen((msg) => print("Msg received : ${msg.data}"));
}
```

It's working well, but it's not enough secure I think.
Thank you for your help, again.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to achieve trustworthy encryption with an ordinary browser without paying for an SSL certificate.  You need to learn about MITM attacks and chain of trust.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: It's that I thought... So, without this certificate, how I can do for protect the information?

Comment: You can't.  An attacker can completely replace all of your code before anything runs.

Comment: So no way to secure the information of my customer ? Perhaps with other method, who is not websocket ?

Comment: You **need** an SSL certificate.  You also need to learn more about security and cryptography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a self-signed certificate: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self

Using it, the data will be protected from voyeurs. Unless somebody steal your private key, then that thief could decrypt the communication.

BUT, as the certificate is not signed by a valid CA, your client has no certainty that is connecting where he think he is, enablin MITM attacks as @SLaKs pointed out. This is, somebody could sit between your customer and the server, and then read everything.

So if your customer, once aware of this, does not want to pay for a certificate, and is keen to accept that the browser will issue a warning about the CA signature each time it connects, you can use the self-signed one.